# Postman and Silverstripe API endpoint multipart form with file upload

Tags: api, file, postman, multipartform-data, silverstripe

I have created a very simple method to accept incoming multipart form-data that includes a file. I'm using Postman to do my testing. I can't seem to get the `$_FILES` data it just returns an empty array. I can get all the other data.

My method looks like:

```
public function UploadFile($request){
    Debug::dump($request);
    Debug::dump($_FILES);
}
```

In Postman I have:

url: http://localhost/sensibel-cms/home/UploadFile

headers: none

body: form-data

key1: UID

value1: 1234567

file: testupload.png

I've attached a image that might make more sense:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot it seems you are doing the right thing, in particular, headers `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` look good. However, the header `Origin: chrome-extension ...` indicates you are using Postman Chrome app which is [deprecated](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/11/01/goodbye-postman-chrome-app/), so try replicating the issue using Postman native app.